# Simple AES encryption decryption with openssl library in C

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, openssl, aes

I want to encrypt a struct containing few String and then decrypt it. I tried following code. The original code is found from the web and it was working perfectly. I change the input of it to a struct. following is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

typedef struct ticket { /* test field */
int ticketId;
char username[20];
    char date[20];
} USR_TICKET;

// a simple hex-print routine. could be modified to print 16 bytes-per-line
static void hex_print(const void* pv, size_t len)
{
const unsigned char * p = (const unsigned char*)pv;
if (NULL == pv)
    printf("NULL");
else
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i<len;++i)
        printf("%02X ", *p++);
}
printf("\n");
}

// main entrypoint
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int keylength;
    printf("Give a key length [only 128 or 192 or 256!]:\n");
    scanf("%d", &keylength);

    /* generate a key with a given length */
    unsigned char aes_key[keylength/8];
    memset(aes_key, 0, keylength/8);
    if (!RAND_bytes(aes_key, keylength/8))
        exit(-1);

    /* input struct creation */
    size_t inputslength = sizeof(USR_TICKET);
    USR_TICKET ticket;
    ticket.ticketId = 1;
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    strftime(ticket.date, 20, "%Y-%m-%d", localtime(&now));
    strcpy(ticket.username, "ravinda");

    printf("Username - %s\n", ticket.username);
    printf("Ticket Id - %d\n", ticket.ticketId);
    printf("Date - %s\n", ticket.date);

    /* init vector */
    unsigned char iv_enc[AES_BLOCK_SIZE], iv_dec[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    RAND_bytes(iv_enc, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    memcpy(iv_dec, iv_enc, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    // buffers for encryption and decryption
    const size_t encslength = ((inputslength + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    unsigned char enc_out[encslength];
    unsigned char dec_out[inputslength];
    memset(enc_out, 0, sizeof(enc_out));
    memset(dec_out, 0, sizeof(dec_out));

    // so i can do with this aes-cbc-128 aes-cbc-192 aes-cbc-256
    AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, keylength, &enc_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char *)&ticket, enc_out, inputslength, &enc_key, iv_enc, AES_ENCRYPT);

    AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key, keylength, &dec_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(enc_out, dec_out, encslength, &dec_key, iv_dec, AES_DECRYPT);

    printf("original:\t");
    hex_print((unsigned char *)&ticket, inputslength);

    printf("encrypt:\t");
    hex_print(enc_out, sizeof(enc_out));

    printf("decrypt:\t");
    hex_print(dec_out, sizeof(dec_out));

    USR_TICKET * dyc = (USR_TICKET *)dec_out;
    printf("Username - %s\n", dyc->username);
    printf("Ticket Id - %d\n", dyc->ticketId);
    printf("Date - %s\n", dyc->date);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is only first two members of the struct is decrypting correctly. After that data get currupted. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I raised this as a bug in OpenSSL - please see the edit on my answer. General consensus is that the appropriate `EVP` routines should be used rather than these low-level functions.

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would *almost* go so far as to say this is a problem with OpenSSL. It seems that when the `length` parameter passed to `AES_cbc_encrypt` is > `AES_BLOCK_SIZE` but not an integral multiple thereof (i.e. `length mod AES_BLOCK_SIZE != 0`), then the last block is encrypted using the *initial* IV and not the previous block of ciphertext as should be the case for CBC mode.

You can fix this in one of two ways:

Copy your struct to a buffer whose size is an integral multiple of `AES_BLOCK_SIZE`, or encrypt in two parts - the full blocks, followed by a single partial block. The latter has the advantage of avoiding additional memory usage and can be done as follows:

```
size_t fullBlocks = inputslength - (inputslength % AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
size_t remainingBlock = inputslength - fullBlocks;

AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char *)&ticket, enc_out, fullBlocks, &enc_key, iv_enc, AES_ENCRYPT);
AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char *)&ticket + fullBlocks, enc_out + fullBlocks, remainingBlock, &enc_key, iv_enc, AES_ENCRYPT);
```

You should then be able to decrypt as you currently are without issue. It's worth noting however that you should declare `dec_out` as the same size as `enc_out`, because you're currently overrunning the `dec_out` buffer when decrypting.

**Edit:**

I raised this as a bug in OpenSSL: https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3182&user=guest&pass=guest and whilst there is some argument over whether this is actually a bug, or just (undocumented) undefined behavior, the general consensus is that the `EVP` routines should be used instead, rather than these low-level functions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be in the struct you are using, basically because of the struct padding and member sizes. Try to serialize your input and it must work. in a simple way, try to allocate one char buffer and copy your struct contents to the buffer one by one and try to encrypt that buffer and while decrypting also follow the same method. Post here what you are observing after that. We must be able to comment better on that.

Answer (score 2):

The original code has done the padding for you. The problem is that you passed the wrong plaintext length to AES function. You should pass `encslength`(padded length) to `AES_cbc_encrypt`. Just change this line

```
AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char *)&ticket, enc_out, inputslength, &enc_key, iv_enc, AES_ENCRYPT);
```

to

```
AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char *)&ticket, enc_out, encslength, &enc_key, iv_enc, AES_ENCRYPT);
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Doing as you indicate would read beyond the end of the struct when its size is not a multiple of the block size.

Comment: @Iridium you're right. He needs to copy ticket to a buffer of size `encslength` to avoid this.

Comment: Well I'm surprised now. The code which I post, I ran it on my desktop machine running Ubuntu 12.04. Today I ran same code on my laptop which runs Ubuntu 10.04 and guess what decryption works fine without anykind of problem. Now I'm pulling my hair thinking what cause that.

Comment: Maybe check the OpenSSL version?

Answer (score 0):

At least I also think it is not a good practise to use `struct` and `sizeof(a_struct_type)` here.

The actual binary sequence of the `struct USR_TICKET` and the result of  `sizeof` will vary according to different padding and byte alignment implementation.

Here is the test result.

1) Firstly, I download the latest openssl1.0.2c and build it, and test the code here with this library on OS X 10.10.3, the code works fine.

2) And I tried to run the test for 5 times. Each time, even the `original` plain text will changed due to padding of `struct`(on my OS, the last 4 bytes will be changed every time).

3) So,the same input to the `struct` produced different `plain text`, which finally produced different cipher text. The user might be confused by the different cipher text output, when they try to encrypt the same input info(here `raving, 1, 2015-6-25`) with the same key and iv.

4) Furthermore, just change the `struct` internal definition, which will produce the same concern in description (3).

```
typedef struct ticket { /* test field */
int ticketId;
char username[19]; // here try to change from 20 to 19
    char date[20]; // here try to change from 20 to other size
} USR_TICKET;
```

PS. Some outputs result from above description(2),

Output1:

```
Give a key length [only 128 or 192 or 256!]:
128
Username - ravinda
Ticket Id - 1
Date - 2015-06-25
original:   01 00 00 00 72 61 76 69 6E 64 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 32 30 31 35 2D 30 36 2D 32 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 58 BB 3A 50 
encrypt:    BA 32 86 CC 71 55 2F 73 ED A1 C9 DE 00 32 1A 20 D9 A5 16 52 8A CD F0 F7 38 04 76 38 5A 47 35 3B A3 07 97 41 C4 C2 05 53 74 93 91 26 7E DE 40 47 
decrypt:    01 00 00 00 72 61 76 69 6E 64 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 32 30 31 35 2D 30 36 2D 32 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 58 BB 3A 50 
Username - ravinda
Ticket Id - 1
Date - 2015-06-25
```

Output2:

```
Give a key length [only 128 or 192 or 256!]:
128
Username - ravinda
Ticket Id - 1
Date - 2015-06-25
original:   01 00 00 00 72 61 76 69 6E 64 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 32 30 31 35 2D 30 36 2D 32 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 58 0B 10 5A 
encrypt:    BE 60 0F FC 17 A3 42 4A 95 7C 39 DB BF 2C BA 59 42 DC 0C AD B2 20 76 6A 04 E3 DE 11 3E D0 AF 88 A5 B9 D2 25 D4 AE F0 B7 82 9F 13 39 80 39 61 9D 
decrypt:    01 00 00 00 72 61 76 69 6E 64 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 32 30 31 35 2D 30 36 2D 32 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 58 0B 10 5A 
Username - ravinda
Ticket Id - 1
Date - 2015-06-25
```